# "Может быть" - вводное слово или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Я не привык доверяться word'овским ошибкам, но он показывает, что запятые в скобках должны стоять, хотя мне кажется, что они не нужны.

1 - Кто знает, может быть(,) эта особенность поможет им.

2 - Он хотел узнать, может быть(,) король сам что-то расскажет

Answer (score 2):

Word абсолютно прав: *может быть* в обоих предложениях — вводное выражение.

> **может быть**
>
> вводное выражение и в значении сказуемого
>
> 1. Вводное выражение. То же, что «вероятно, возможно». Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми. Подробно о пунктуации при вводных
>    словах см. в [Приложении 2](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/393/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C).
>
> *И когда с другим по переулку // Ты пойдешь, болтая про любовь, // **Может быть**, я выйду на прогулку, // И с тобою встретимся мы вновь.* С. Есенин, Ты меня не любишь, не жалеешь... *Марья Ивановна
> нравилась мне более обыкновенного. Мысль, что, **может быть**, вижу
> ее в последний раз, придавала ей в моих глазах что-то трогательное.*
> А. Пушкин, Капитанская дочка. *Я, **может быть**, более, нежели всякий
> другой, имею право на этот портрет.* Н. Гоголь, Портрет.
>
> https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/605/%E2%86%91%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_2

Продолжение о *может быть* в значении сказуемого я цитировать не буду: это явно не ваш случай.